# How can i solve 'error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number' appearing in Etsi OSM Client?

Tags: curl

Every time I try to connect to North Bound Interface (NBI) to run commands like this one "osm --hostname nbi:9999 version" via Etsi OSM Client, I get the following error:

```
**(35, 'error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number')
Maybe "--hostname" option or OSM_HOSTNAME environment variable needs to be specified**
```

I tried the same command via curl to connect to NBI (curl --verbose https://nbi:9999/osm/version) and the result is quite the same:

```
*   Trying 10.152.183.66:9999...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to nbi (10.152.183.66) port 9999 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

For commands like the one used before I can temporary fix the problem by running curl with http instead of https. How can I fix the problem using https instead of http? And how can I fix the problem in OSM Client? (I need to use OSM Client, not curl)

Answer (score 3):

> For commands like the one used before I can temporary fix the problem by running curl with http instead of https. How can I fix the problem using https instead of http?

The error is caused by trying to access a server with HTTPS, even though the server speaks only plain HTTP. This might be because the server is unable to support HTTPS in the first place, does not have HTTPS properly configured or has HTTPS configured and enabled but on a different port (i.e. not 9999) than accessed.

So either this needs to be done by properly setting up the server or by using the proper HTTPS enabled port when accessing the server by the client.